# Need auto play of videos on android and ios mobile devices

Tags: jwplayer, autoplay

I want to auto play of videos in andriod and ios mobile devices.I have used the jwplayer for playing videos and set option autostart as true but not working on mobile devices.But any how i need auto play.
So anybody can help me out?

Comment: Hi, are you using the JWPlayer SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Autostart does not work on mobile. This is due to OS developers efforts to save user bandwidth, and is considered a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But any how i need to auto play video in mobile browser,so you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<video muted autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline poster=""  loop >
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```